# Issue with request module in python

Tags: python

I'm not figuring out to resolve this issue.

I installed `python/pip` and it works.. but i'm not able to import ***requests module*** inside my python script.

if i launch this command:

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

i'm going to receive this as output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Requirement already up-to-date: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

So, if i launch a simple script:

```
#! usr/bin/python

import requests


printl("hello")
```

i get this error:

```
 File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

**UPDATE with sys.path output**

```
[ '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson-2.0.9-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

what's wrong?

Comment: What does `import sys; print(sys.path)` give you? Is the path `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in it?

Comment: @AnandSKumar can you see question updates?

Comment: seems like you have multiple installations of Python, pip is installing `requests` for some `/usr/local/bin/python` , instead of `/usr/bin/python` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar How i can resolve this problem?

Comment: Well why do you have multiple installations for python? You can try running your program with the python version for which you installed requests , by giving the shebang as - `#!/usr/local/bin/python` . Also can you tell us what does `which python` gives?

Comment: I tried to add `#!/usr/local/bin/python` and doesn't work,  `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: hmm, what does `ls /usr/local/bin/` give? Do you see any `python` inside it?

Comment: @AnandSKumar i have python2.7 inside this path.

Comment: @AnandSKumar i wrote `#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7` and i got the same error.

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes, the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

If someone has got the same problem, simply run the scripts with the version of python which has the  modules.

So for example, in my case this works:

```
$python2.7 test.py
```

Comment: I would recommend using  [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), they make everything much easier.